# Manipulate a data frame where there are multiple colums for each experiment

Tags: r, dataframe

I have many sequencing experiments each with multiple results for each of a few hundred genes, when the data is outputted from another programme it isn't in a useful format for me as all the Experiments and each result are listed along the top and there is one row for each gene. I have written an example data set and how I am currently solving this problem as an example but I would like a more optimal method as my data sets are very large.

```
 col1<- c("","", "gene1", "gene2", "gene3", "gene4")
 col2<- c("Experiment1", "Part 1", "a","b","c","d")
 col3<- c("Experiment1", "Part 2", "e", "f", "g", "h")
 col4<- c("Experiment2", "Part 1", "i", "j", "k", "l")
 col5<- c("Experiment2", "Part 2", "m", "n", "o", "p")
 pp<- data.frame(col1,col2,col3,col4,col5)
 one<-data.frame(pp$col1, pp$col2)
 onetwo<- data.frame(pp$col1,pp$col3)
 two<-data.frame(pp$col1, pp$col4)
 twotwo<-data.frame(pp$col1,pp$col5)

 one$V3[3:6]<-as.character(one[2,2])
 one<-one[-2,]
 one<-one[-1,]
 colnames(one)<- c("gene", "Experiment 1", "part")

 onetwo$V3[3:6]<-as.character(onetwo[2,2])
 onetwo<-onetwo[-2,]
 onetwo<-onetwo[-1,]
 colnames(onetwo)<- c("gene", "Experiment 1", "part")

 x1<-rbind(one, onetwo)

 two$V3[3:6]<-as.character(two[2,2])
 two<-two[-2,]
 two<-two[-1,]
 colnames(two)<- c("gene", "Experiment 2", "part")


 twotwo$V3[3:6]<-as.character(twotwo[2,2])
 twotwo<-twotwo[-2,]
 twotwo<-twotwo[-1,]
 colnames(twotwo)<- c("gene", "Experiment 2", "part")

 x2<-rbind(two, twotwo)

 x3<-merge(x1,x2)
```

I apologise for the large amount of code but I am unable to verbalise this operation specifically. pp is the example data frame and x3 is the format I require. Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be a shorter way to do it:

```
pp.new <- as.data.frame(t(pp)[-1,], row.names = 1)
names(pp.new) <- c("experiment", "part", "gene1", "gene2", "gene3", "gene4")
```

which gives:

```
> pp.new
   experiment   part gene1 gene2 gene3 gene4
1 Experiment1 Part 1     a     b     c     d
2 Experiment1 Part 2     e     f     g     h
3 Experiment2 Part 1     i     j     k     l
4 Experiment2 Part 2     m     n     o     p
```

However, it is probably better to transform this into long format with the *reshape2* package:

```
library(reshape2)    
pp.long <- melt(pp.new, id=c("experiment","part"))
```

which results in:

```
> pp.long
    experiment   part variable value
1  Experiment1 Part 1    gene1     a
2  Experiment1 Part 2    gene1     e
3  Experiment2 Part 1    gene1     i
4  Experiment2 Part 2    gene1     m
5  Experiment1 Part 1    gene2     b
6  Experiment1 Part 2    gene2     f
7  Experiment2 Part 1    gene2     j
8  Experiment2 Part 2    gene2     n
9  Experiment1 Part 1    gene3     c
10 Experiment1 Part 2    gene3     g
11 Experiment2 Part 1    gene3     k
12 Experiment2 Part 2    gene3     o
13 Experiment1 Part 1    gene4     d
14 Experiment1 Part 2    gene4     h
15 Experiment2 Part 1    gene4     l
16 Experiment2 Part 2    gene4     p
```

If you want to get a compareable output as in `x3`, you can use the `recast` function (also from the *reshape2* package):

```
recast(pp.new, part + variable ~ experiment, id.var=c("experiment","part"), value.var = "value")
```

which gives:

```
    part variable Experiment1 Experiment2
1 Part 1    gene1           a           i
2 Part 1    gene2           b           j
3 Part 1    gene3           c           k
4 Part 1    gene4           d           l
5 Part 2    gene1           e           m
6 Part 2    gene2           f           n
7 Part 2    gene3           g           o
8 Part 2    gene4           h           p
```