# How to read a data set where variables are stored as rows, and some variable names contain "#"

Tags: r, import

I have a fairly large (about 1200 variables with 14 observations each) data set, stored in a text file, with a very weird and definitely not `tidy` structure. In practice each variable is stored as a row, instead than as a column, and the first and second row are respectively the variable name, and the measurement unit for that variable. Here is a sample data set:

```
Date    --- 1/19/2016   1/19/2016   1/19/2016   1/19/2016   1/19/2016   1/19/2016   1/19/2016   1/19/2016   1/19/2016   1/19/2016   1/19/2016   1/19/2016   1/19/2016   1/19/2016
PT-AMB#SRV  V   1.403400    1.403207    1.403265    1.403326    1.403454    1.403783    1.404924    1.404962    1.405291    1.404951    1.404685    1.404812    1.404433    1.404428
PS1-SEC20#SRV   V   2.395769    2.416003    2.362276    2.253045    2.139873    1.939328    2.450442    2.294791    2.085946    1.929666    2.634747    3.067008    3.081949    3.095456
```

The first variable is called `Date` and it's nondimensional (units `---`), the second one is `PT-AMB#SRV` and measured in volts `V`, and so on. NOTE: two entries on the same row are separated by a tab in the original file. I'm not sure if this is conserved once I copy&paste data here on Stack Overflow.

First of all, I tried to read in data like this:

```
df=read.table("TEST.txt",sep="\t")
```

I get the following error:

```
Error in scan(file, what, nmax, sep, dec, quote, skip, nlines, na.strings,  : 
  line 2 did not have 16 elements
```

The error goes away if I manually edit the second (and the third) variable names, changing the `#` to a `-`.

The first question is: why is this happening, and how can I prevent it from happening? If I need to change all `#` to `-` in all variable names, how can I do that automatically? Preferably in `R`, otherwise the command line is fine (I work in Windows).

Second question: after modifying all the `#` (just two in this sample data set), I read it with

```
 df=read.table("TEST.txt",sep="\t")
```

I get:

```
             V1  V2        V3        V4        V5        V6        V7        V8        V9       V10       V11       V12       V13       V14       V15       V16
1          Date --- 1/19/2016 1/19/2016 1/19/2016 1/19/2016 1/19/2016 1/19/2016 1/19/2016 1/19/2016 1/19/2016 1/19/2016 1/19/2016 1/19/2016 1/19/2016 1/19/2016
2    PT-AMB-SRV   V  1.403400  1.403207  1.403265  1.403326  1.403454  1.403783  1.404924  1.404962  1.405291  1.404951  1.404685  1.404812  1.404433  1.404428
3 PS1-SEC20-SRV   V  2.395769  2.416003  2.362276  2.253045  2.139873  1.939328  2.450442  2.294791  2.085946  1.929666  2.634747  3.067008  3.081949  3.095456
```

I then try to transpose `df`, so that variables are stored in columns:

```
df_t=t(df)
```

I get:

```
    [,1]        [,2]         [,3]           
V1  "Date"      "PT-AMB-SRV" "PS1-SEC20-SRV"
V2  "---"       "V"          "V"            
V3  "1/19/2016" "1.403400"   "2.395769"     
V4  "1/19/2016" "1.403207"   "2.416003"     
V5  "1/19/2016" "1.403265"   "2.362276"     
V6  "1/19/2016" "1.403326"   "2.253045"     
V7  "1/19/2016" "1.403454"   "2.139873"     
V8  "1/19/2016" "1.403783"   "1.939328"     
V9  "1/19/2016" "1.404924"   "2.450442"     
V10 "1/19/2016" "1.404962"   "2.294791"     
V11 "1/19/2016" "1.405291"   "2.085946"     
V12 "1/19/2016" "1.404951"   "1.929666"     
V13 "1/19/2016" "1.404685"   "2.634747"     
V14 "1/19/2016" "1.404812"   "3.067008"     
V15 "1/19/2016" "1.404433"   "3.081949"     
V16 "1/19/2016" "1.404428"   "3.095456"
```

No more a data frame, but an array of characters. Definitely not what I want to. How can I make it so that variables are stored in columns (tidy data set)? I thought the problem was the column containing the measurement units, but removing it before transposing with

```
df[,"V2"]=NULL
```

doesn't solve anything. Maybe `tidyr` could help here, but I don't know how.

Comment: have a look at the parameter `comment.char` from `read.table` function (`?read.table`) (by default it is `#` and so everything that follows it considered comment and thus not imported. good news is, you can define it to be anything you want...)

Comment: Thanks! `df=read.table("TEST.txt",sep="\t",comment.char="")` solved the first issue. What about the second? I'm still not able to transpose `df` and get another dataframe, with the correct variable names and values correctly interpreted either as dates, real numbers, integers, etc., depending on the variable.

Comment: OK as @Cath says, but to get you started try just transposing the rows that are numeric: `df_t <- t(df[,3:1200])`. then manually add the column names: `colnames(df_t)<- df[,1]`... then go read a bit.

Comment: [see here for an example on the use of `t` to transpose a dataframe](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34997164/manipulate-a-data-frame-where-there-are-multiple-colums-for-each-experiment/34997603#34997603)

Comment: @StephenHenderson, there are thousands of rows and of course I only showed some. Of course it's not just the first two ones which are not numeric: there are many such rows, "dispersed" inside the data set. About reading, what exactly do you suggest I may read? I read Whickam's paper on `tidyr`: he says that variables should be stored in columns, not in rows, but he doesn't show which commands to use to fix this. I tried googling for "r move variables from rows to columns". I found some hints about using `dcast` and had a look at the doc entry, but I don't understand how to use it here.

Comment: @Jaap, thanks! A useful comment which actually  points to something to read. I will have a look and let you know if it solves my issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the data into DF0, transpose it and use `type.convert` to get appropriate classes for the columns.  Set the names and convert the first column to `"Date"` class using the appropriate format string.

```
# replace text = Lines with file = "myfile.dat"
DF0 <- read.table( text = Lines, colClasses = "character", comment = "" )
L <- lapply( as.data.frame( tail( t(DF0), -2 ), stringsAsFactors = FALSE ), type.convert )
DF <- setNames( as.data.frame(L), DF0[[1]] )
DF$Date <- as.Date( DF$Date, format = "%m/%d/%Y" )
```

The result is:

```
> DF
         Date PT-AMB#SRV PS1-SEC20#SRV
1  2016-01-19   1.403400      2.395769
2  2016-01-19   1.403207      2.416003
3  2016-01-19   1.403265      2.362276
4  2016-01-19   1.403326      2.253045
5  2016-01-19   1.403454      2.139873
6  2016-01-19   1.403783      1.939328
7  2016-01-19   1.404924      2.450442
8  2016-01-19   1.404962      2.294791
9  2016-01-19   1.405291      2.085946
10 2016-01-19   1.404951      1.929666
11 2016-01-19   1.404685      2.634747
12 2016-01-19   1.404812      3.067008
13 2016-01-19   1.404433      3.081949
14 2016-01-19   1.404428      3.095456
```

**Note:** We used this input:

```
Lines <- 
"Date    --- 1/19/2016   1/19/2016   1/19/2016   1/19/2016   1/19/2016   1/19/2016   1/19/2016   1/19/2016   1/19/2016   1/19/2016   1/19/2016   1/19/2016   1/19/2016   1/19/2016
PT-AMB#SRV  V   1.403400    1.403207    1.403265    1.403326    1.403454    1.403783    1.404924    1.404962    1.405291    1.404951    1.404685    1.404812    1.404433    1.404428
PS1-SEC20#SRV   V   2.395769    2.416003    2.362276    2.253045    2.139873    1.939328    2.450442    2.294791    2.085946    1.929666    2.634747    3.067008    3.081949    3.095456"
```

Comment: Man, you're great! It works **perfectly**, even if in the actual data set there are many other "nasty" lines, in addition to those I used for the example. Just two clarifications: why is `colClasses` needed in `read.table`? I had a look at the corresponding entry in `read.table` help, but I can't say I understood a lot. Also, I think I get the goal of the second line, but I'm not sure what is the reason for the `-2` in `as.data.frame( tail( t(DF0), -2 ))`. Could you elucidate a bit?

Comment: The `colClasses="character"` makes everything character.  When we transpose it then it will all be coereced to a matrix whose entries must be all of the same class so for safety sake we ensure it's character to begin with.    `tail(..., -2)` removes the header and the units.