# Read N files and merge them in a single dataframe, removing the first two column for N-1 files

Tags: r, file-io, dataframe

I have a lot of txt files in the same directory, each one having more or less this structure (columns are tab-separated):

```
Date    --- 22/01/2016  22/01/2016  22/01/2016  22/01/2016  22/01/2016  22/01/2016  22/01/2016  22/01/2016  25/01/2016  18/02/2016  18/02/2016  18/02/2016
Time    --- 14:51:05    15:04:07    15:29:37    15:50:44    17:09:32    17:25:16    17:35:32    17:55:03    18:14:12    15:08:34    15:13:37    15:17:52
Test Condition  --- abab    abab    abab    abab    abab    abab    abab    abab    abab    abab    abab    abab
SN  --- 1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10  11  12
Recalc level    ---                                             
Value Type  --- VALUE   VALUE   VALUE   VALUE   VALUE   VALUE   VALUE   VALUE   VALUE   VALUE   VALUE   VALUE
p0  b   14.575415   14.5033 14.358027   14.414596   14.245372   14.700387   14.362854   14.625043   14.629057   14.623121   14.56988    14.503992
p1  b   13.93296    14.012461   13.978808   14.137786   13.922123   14.121563   13.912913   14.22689    14.004849   13.983506   13.980593   13.988037
p2  b   16.000525   17.177015   18.651033   20.195074   19.578585   16.702759   17.720543   18.693916   16.046732   16.034887   16.406563   17.001293
p3  b   15.480929   16.768116   18.097382   19.70241    19.14805    16.397367   17.336346   18.273314   15.578776   15.532222   16.045994   16.606255
p4  b   18.55571    22.083971   26.322443   29.608585   28.409742   20.452003   23.945446   26.123919   18.625406   18.552509   19.780315   21.549072
p5  b   18.056015   21.726614   25.950783   29.434395   28.267536   20.089258   23.641006   25.879562   18.131035   18.066408   19.404228   21.19585
p6  b   22.659739   29.856588   36.771679   41.626987   40.687416   26.412348   32.951481   36.212402   22.768396   22.618305   25.209219   28.963219
```

The actual files have much more rows and columns than this example. 
I want to read them, and merge them in a single dataframe. The dataframe will need some tidying, since here variables are stored as rows and observations as columns, but for that I follow this [excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35015923/1711271). Before doing that, I need to read the files and do the merging: my idea was

```
read_files <- function(directory, filenames = NULL) {
    # 'directory' is a character variable indicating the location of the
    # txt files

    # 'filenames' is an optional character vector specifying the filenames 
    # to be read

    # Return a data frame containing all the files read

    # make a list of txt files to be read
    if (is.null(filenames)) {
        filenames <- dir(path = directory, pattern ="\\.txt")
    }
    filenames <- paste(directory, filenames, sep="/")    

    # read data from the files in filenames
    alldata <- lapply(filenames, read.table,
                                 sep="\t",           
                                 colClasses = "character")

    ## merge the list of data frames in a single data frame
    data=do.call("cbind",alldata)   
}
```

I use the argument `colClasses = "character"` because, as explained in the answer linked above, when I then transpose the data frame, it will be coerced to a matrix, whose elements are all of the same type, thus for safety I ensure that that type is `character`. Now, the problem is that in each file the first and the second column are repeated (they are the variable names and the measurement units). Thus, before `do.call("cbind",alldata)`, I need to remove all these "header columns", except for the first file. Of course the number of columns for each file is different: the only invariants are the number of rows, and the fact that the first and the second columns must be discarded. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmmm, it says I shouldn't answer my question but since I found a solution and I got no working answer, I thought I would share it. Maybe it will be useful for someone else, or it will prompt better answers.

```
read_MyView_exports <- function(directory, filenames = NULL) {
    ## 'directory' is a character vector of length 1 indicating
    ## the location of the MyView txt exports

    ## 'filenames' is an optional character vector specifying the filenames 
    ## to be read

    ## Return a data frame containing all the files read

    ## make a list of txt files to be read
    if (is.null(filenames)) {
        filenames <- dir(path = directory, pattern ="\\.txt.*?")
    }
    filenames <- paste(directory, filenames, sep="/")    

    ## read first file
    df1 <- read.table(filenames[1],
                      sep="\t",           # data in MyView export are tab-separated
                      colClasses = "character")
    ## eliminate the column with measurement units
    df1[,2]=NULL

    ## when reading the other files, we need to skip the first two columns, since
    ## they contain varnames and units, so we define a useful wrapper for read.table
    read.and.skip <- function(file){
        df <- read.table(file, sep="\t", colClasses = "character")
        df[,-2:-1,drop=FALSE]
    }


    ## read data from the files in filenames
    alldata <- lapply(filenames, read.and.skip)

    ## merge the list of data frames in a single data frame
    data=do.call("cbind",alldata)
    data=cbind(df1, data)

}
```

The idea is to read the first file separately from the others, so I have one copy of the first column, the one with the varnames, which I'll need later to tidy up my dataframe as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35015923/1711271). Then I wrap `read.table` in a small function `read.and.skip` which reads a file and drops the first two columns, I read all files with `lapply` and finally I bind the dataframe built from the first file, with that built from all the other files.

Comment: I ended up accepting my answer, because I didn't get another working one. Hope that's ok with the site guidelines.

Answer (score 0):

Does this work?

```
# read data from the files in filenames
    alldata <- lapply(filenames, read.table(skip = 2),
                                 sep="\t",           
                                 colClasses = "character")
```

Anyway, I'm not sure you want to `cbind()`... what I would do is: Using dplyr package, convert all data to "tidy format", so that you have a 'long' format rather than a 'wide' format for each file. This will get rid of the inconsistencies and might remove the need to read everything as character. Then instead of cbinding all these dataframes that might inconsistent observation numbers you can `rbind()` everything... then when you're done, you can convert to whatever format you wanted.

Also look into `bind_rows()` and `bind_cols()` in dplyr.

Comment: It doesn't work because `skip` skips rows, not columns. Apparently you didn't notice that the observations in these files are in columns, instead than rows.

Comment: Probably fastest to read everything in and throw those 2 columns out?

Comment: Ok, but there are two columns to delete for each file I read...so if I read 100 files, I need to delete 98 columns (I keep the columns from the first file, because I'll use them to get through variables names). The problem is that, since each file has a different number of columns, once I merged all files together I don't know which are the indexes of the columns to remove. If, instead of using `lapply` to read the files , I used a `for` loop, it would be easy to remove the first two columns each time I read a file, but `for` loops in R are quite slow.